# Statistical test and p-value for 2 weighted average

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, weighted-mean

I was wondering whether there exist a statistical test to prove that two weighted averages are indeed statistically different (e.g., p-value < 0.05).

An example is provided by the plot below.
Suppose that we have two groups of devices (blue and green). For each group we test their breaking point (in degrees Celsius).
So, numerically, we measure that for the blue group, around 20 devices break at -7, around 120 at -5 and so on. We than compute that the weighted average for the blue group is -3.
We do exactly the same for the green group, and we get a weighted average of 3.
Is there any test to prove that the difference is significant?

Is there any test that works also if on the x axis the values to consider are different?

[image]

Comment: How where the weight determined? Somehow calculated from the data, or given apriori?

Comment: computed... so lets say that x goes from -10 to 10:
wavg = sum (x=[-10,10]) x*count / sum(count). The weight are simply an empirical count of the appearance of x in the data

Comment: So, that means that you have *grouped data*. So is this just frequency weights, or is there also a binning approximation of originally continuous data? And, this is information that should have been  in the post! please add it there as an edit.

Comment: I edited the post with a better example explaining the empirical concept. Sorry if it was not clear

Comment: These look like the usual arithmetic means to me.  Weighting values by the counts is merely an algebraic shortcut for computing them.